# Can't click on links; Thinking of Overlapping (padding? margin? )

Tags: html, css, padding

I am working on a website but I've got a problem with making the navbar. I have created a navbar but when I want to click on the left ones they aren't clickable and the right ones are.. my question is: How do I fix it I've tried different methodes but I am a noob and hope/think there's a simple solution for this that I don't know about.

Thanks anyways.

CSS:

```
.navlay{
background-image: url(./img/noise.png);
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
height: 7%;
margin-top: 19.4%;
margin-right:10%; 
margin-left:10%;
}


.left {
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
margin-left: 8%;
margin-top: 20.3%;

text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
list-style: none;

font-size: 100%;
font-family: webbie;
font-weight: bold;
}

.right {
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
margin-top: 20.3%;

list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;

font-size: 100%;
font-family: webbie;
font-weight: bold;
}


.left li {
float: left;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
}

.right li {
float: left;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
}

.right li:first-child {
float: left;
padding-left: 80%;
padding-right: 3%;
}

.left li a {
color: #949494;
}

.right li a {
color: #949494;
}

.left li a:hover {
opacity: 0.6;
color: #949494;
cursor: pointer;
}

.right li a:hover {
opacity: 0.6;
color: #949494;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/na5pP.png

HTML:

```
        <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="apply.php">Apply</a></li>
            <li><a href="members.php">Team-Members</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to click on left because of width of right that you have set. You can try following css.

Here's [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5p4E/2/)

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 20.3%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: webbie;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 20.3%;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: webbie;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.right li:first-child {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 80%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```